# Implementation of GANs

Tags: python, generative-models

I'm working on a particle physics dataset and want to know what libraries I would need to implement GANs and other generative algorithms like  in Python.

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/12_Adversarial_Noise_MNIST.ipynb) and [here](https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/11_gan.py).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Keras, docs found [here](https://keras.io/), to train a GAN. I have provided a GAN implementation in a previous answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27715/using-generative-adversarial-network-to-generate-single-image/27787#27787). Here is an alternative version that I have used more recently (found online).

```
import numpy as np
import time
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, Dropout
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ElapsedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
    def elapsed(self,sec):
        if sec < 60:
            return str(sec) + " sec"
        elif sec < (60 * 60):
            return str(sec / 60) + " min"
        else:
            return str(sec / (60 * 60)) + " hr"
    def elapsed_time(self):
        print("Elapsed: %s " % self.elapsed(time.time() - self.start_time) )

class DCGAN(object):
    def __init__(self, img_rows=28, img_cols=28, channel=1):

        self.img_rows = img_rows
        self.img_cols = img_cols
        self.channel = channel
        self.D = None   # discriminator
        self.G = None   # generator
        self.AM = None  # adversarial model
        self.DM = None  # discriminator model

    # (W−F+2P)/S+1
    def discriminator(self):
        if self.D:
            return self.D
        self.D = Sequential()
        depth = 64
        dropout = 0.4
        # In: 28 x 28 x 1, depth = 1
        # Out: 14 x 14 x 1, depth=64
        input_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channel)
        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*1, 5, strides=2, input_shape=input_shape,\
            padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*2, 5, strides=2, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*4, 5, strides=2, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))

        self.D.add(Conv2D(depth*8, 5, strides=1, padding='same'))
        self.D.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        self.D.add(Dropout(dropout))

        # Out: 1-dim probability
        self.D.add(Flatten())
        self.D.add(Dense(1))
        self.D.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
        self.D.summary()
        return self.D

    def generator(self):
        if self.G:
            return self.G
        self.G = Sequential()
        dropout = 0.4
        depth = 64+64+64+64
        dim = 7
        # In: 100
        # Out: dim x dim x depth
        self.G.add(Dense(dim*dim*depth, input_dim=100))
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))
        self.G.add(Reshape((dim, dim, depth)))
        self.G.add(Dropout(dropout))

        # In: dim x dim x depth
        # Out: 2*dim x 2*dim x depth/2
        self.G.add(UpSampling2D())
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/2), 5, padding='same'))
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))

        self.G.add(UpSampling2D())
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/4), 5, padding='same'))
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))

        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/8), 5, padding='same'))
        self.G.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
        self.G.add(Activation('relu'))

        # Out: 28 x 28 x 1 grayscale image [0.0,1.0] per pix
        self.G.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, 5, padding='same'))
        self.G.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
        self.G.summary()
        return self.G

    def discriminator_model(self):
        if self.DM:
            return self.DM
        optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0002, decay=6e-8)
        self.DM = Sequential()
        self.DM.add(self.discriminator())
        self.DM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,\
            metrics=['accuracy'])
        return self.DM

    def adversarial_model(self):
        if self.AM:
            return self.AM
        optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=3e-8)
        self.AM = Sequential()
        self.AM.add(self.generator())
        self.AM.add(self.discriminator())
        self.AM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,\
            metrics=['accuracy'])
        return self.AM

class MNIST_DCGAN(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.img_rows = 28
        self.img_cols = 28
        self.channel = 1

        self.x_train = input_data.read_data_sets("mnist",\
            one_hot=True).train.images
        self.x_train = self.x_train.reshape(-1, self.img_rows,\
            self.img_cols, 1).astype(np.float32)

        self.DCGAN = DCGAN()
        self.discriminator =  self.DCGAN.discriminator_model()
        self.adversarial = self.DCGAN.adversarial_model()
        self.generator = self.DCGAN.generator()

    def train(self, train_steps=2000, batch_size=256, save_interval=0):
        noise_input = None
        if save_interval>0:
            noise_input = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[16, 100])
        for i in range(train_steps):
            images_train = self.x_train[np.random.randint(0,
                self.x_train.shape[0], size=batch_size), :, :, :]
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[batch_size, 100])
            images_fake = self.generator.predict(noise)
            x = np.concatenate((images_train, images_fake))
            y = np.ones([2*batch_size, 1])
            y[batch_size:, :] = 0
            d_loss = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(x, y)

            y = np.ones([batch_size, 1])
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[batch_size, 100])
            a_loss = self.adversarial.train_on_batch(noise, y)
            log_mesg = "%d: [D loss: %f, acc: %f]" % (i, d_loss[0], d_loss[1])
            log_mesg = "%s  [A loss: %f, acc: %f]" % (log_mesg, a_loss[0], a_loss[1])
            print(log_mesg)
            if save_interval>0:
                if (i+1)%save_interval==0:
                    self.plot_images(save2file=True, samples=noise_input.shape[0],\
                        noise=noise_input, step=(i+1))

    def plot_images(self, save2file=False, fake=True, samples=16, noise=None, step=0):
        filename = 'mnist.png'
        if fake:
            if noise is None:
                noise = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, size=[samples, 100])
            else:
                filename = "mnist_%d.png" % step
            images = self.generator.predict(noise)
        else:
            i = np.random.randint(0, self.x_train.shape[0], samples)
            images = self.x_train[i, :, :, :]

        plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        for i in range(images.shape[0]):
            plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
            image = images[i, :, :, :]
            image = np.reshape(image, [self.img_rows, self.img_cols])
            plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
            plt.axis('off')
        plt.tight_layout()
        if save2file:
            plt.savefig(filename)
            plt.close('all')
        else:
            plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist_dcgan = MNIST_DCGAN()
    timer = ElapsedTimer()
    mnist_dcgan.train(train_steps=10000, batch_size=256, save_interval=500)
    timer.elapsed_time()
    mnist_dcgan.plot_images(fake=True)
    mnist_dcgan.plot_images(fake=False, save2file=True)
```